# Stacking without z-index?

Tags: html, css, z-index

I searched a lot for how stacking of HTML elements occurs without z-index, however could not find anything concrete. I did find that stacking without z-index occurs in the order of the appearance of the HTML.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Understanding_z-index/Stacking_without_z-index

Is this specification valid for IE? I have two divs enclosed in another div. Both the divs have absolute position:

```
<div>
    <div id"div1" style="position:absolute"></div>
    <div id"div2" style="position:absolute"></div> 
</div>
```

for both the divs, i.e. div1 and div2, the values of `left` and `width` are same. From my understanding about the behavior of CSS here, div2 should always overlap div1. What is the possibility that 'div1' will overlap 'div2'?

Comment: "From my understanding about the behavior of css here , div2 should always overlap div2." Huh?

Comment: BoltClock , am i wrong here ? Please correct me .

Comment: "div2 should always overlap div2" Did you mean div1 div2, or div2 div1?

Comment: I'm sorry .It was a typo.I meant  'div2 should always overlap div1' :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your example, according to the [document you've referenced](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Understanding_z-index/Stacking_without_z-index), both `div` elements are **positioned** but without z-index, therefore having equal precedence (note: they do have a higher stacking order than unpositioned elements). This means they are stacked in the order they appear in the markup, with the last declared element having the highest stacking index.

Therefore, according to that definition, there is **no chance** that `div1` will appear above `div2`.

See the [W3C CSS2 specification on stacking context](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/zindex.html#painting-order) for more information. Note **point 8** in particular:

> All positioned descendants with 'z-index: auto' or 'z-index: 0', in tree order.

Basically the order defined in the source is the order of stacking (not specifying `z-index` equates to `z-index: auto`).

Answer (score 3):

If you set the left and top properties of both the DIVs same then the second DIV will always overlap the first one.

Thats what I know.